# Provide is used to pass values to child components, so how does the parent component that sends the provide get the data in the provide itself?

Tags: vue-native

In Vue, provide can pass values to child components

```js
provide('data',ref("I am data for child components"))
```

Subcomponents can use inject to get the value.

How to get the data in the parent component? ?

Answer (score 0):

Normal pass by value:

```js
let data = ref("I am data for child components");
provide('data',data);//This way the parent component can get
```

it and the child component can get it too

Transfer Function:

```js
let children = ref('')
function data(val){

children.value = val;//Get the value passed by the child component
}
provide('data',data);
```

Sub: `let getData = inject('data',data)`
`data` is a function, you can `getData('data for father')`